# Angular ngFor items by 5

Tags: angular

I have a questions which I do not know how to solve. For example when you open a site, there are 5 comments when you click show more 5 more appears when you click again another 5 more appears. Now, everything is printed in once. Maybe you guys know how to deal with this?

Code:

```
    <div class="comment" *ngFor="let comment of comments ">
      <app-student-comment [comment]="comment"></app-student-comment>
    </div>
```

This is how I get data:

```
  this.commentService.getStudentComments({applicationId: this.application.id}).subscribe(data => {
            this.comments = data;
          });
```

Service:

```
  getStudentComments({ applicationId }): Observable<Comment[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Comment[]>(`${this.proxyurl}${this.url}${this.apiPath}/applications/${applicationId}/comments/applicant/visible`);
  }
```

Comment: You can try virtual scrolling with the help of two separate arrays.

Comment: I dont need pagination :) I only need a button which would display 5 more items everytime you click it :)

Comment: Use a pipe that uses a parameter that says how many comments it should currently display, and make your button add +5 to this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a "totalComments" parameter when calling your backend.

```
<div class="comment" *ngFor="let comment of comments ">
    <app-student-comment [comment]="comment"></app-student-comment>
</div>
<button (click)="addComments()">More</button>
```

And in your `page.component.ts`:

```
public totalComments = 5;
public comments = [];

...

ngOnInit() {
    this.getComments();
}

public getComments() {
    this.commentService.getStudentComments({
        applicationId: this.application.id,
        totalComments: this.totalComments
    }).subscribe(data => {
         this.comments = data;
    });
}

public addComments() {
    this.totalComments += 5;
    this.getComments();
}
```

And in your service:

```
getStudentComments({ applicationId, totalComments }): Observable<Comment[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Comment[]>(
    `${this.proxyurl}${this.url}${this.apiPath}/applications/${applicationId}/comments/total/${totalComments}/applicant/visible`
    );
}
```

Then, you would need to update your backend code to use this `totalComments` parameter, for instance with an SQL query:

```
this.db.query(`SELECT * FROM comments LIMIT $1`, [totalComments]);
```

Comment: I updated my question, could you look one more time ?

Comment: And I guess there is no other option than to change backend ?

Comment: You can gather all the comments from the backend, and then change which ones are displayed from the frontend, but I firmly recommend against that, as it can cause big performance issues if there are a lot of comments in your database.